# Is there a Firebase API endpoint to fetch account usage?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-admin

I'm building a SAAS project on Firebase and weighing the pros and cons of multi-tenant architecture vs managed Firebase instances for each account.

One of the key challenges with managed instances is reporting usage. I've searched through Firebase docs but have not been able to find an API endpoint to fetch a Firebase project's account usage (eg bandwidth, function invocations, storage, etc).

Is there a API that I'm missing or is this alternatively possible with core Google Cloud APIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

We just added a REST API to manage projects and the apps in those projects. But there is currently no way to report usage for a project across all Firebase products. It sounds like a useful feature through, so I recommend [filing a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Until a feature is added that fits your needs, you will have to do the tracking from within your own app, or by proxying the tracked functionality through Cloud Functions, where you can then log whatever you need for tracking usage.